# Is it possible to get html sender Button using custom middleware?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, customization, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm completely new dealing with custom `middleware`. I know `HttpContext` can get request body. but I don't know if that might help in my case?

let's assume I use a button with the attribute `dataset` => `data-setting`.

I need to get the value of this attribute.
**Is that possible and how?**

#### html

```
<button type="submit" data-setting="{tab:9,page:20,user,unknowen}"> submit </button>
```

#### c# middleware

```
private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
private readonly ILogger _logger;

public PageSetting(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory logFactory)
{
   _next = next;
   _logger = logFactory.CreateLogger("MyMiddleware");
}

public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
   string getAttribute = httpContext.Request.Body.ToString();
   // how to get the value of [data-setting] attribute !!????

   _logger.LogInformation("MyMiddleware executing..");
   await _next(httpContext);
}
```

Comment: Is your html page contains form?

Comment: yes @KiranJoshi as shown in the code the type of button is submit, and I need to get the HTML of the button who triggers the submit action.

Comment: You want button or button data-attribute value?

Comment: I mean any one of them it's okay. however, I need to do so from custom middleware.

Comment: You can access your button value but not attribute.

Comment: @KiranJoshi what do you mean?

Comment: you can not able to access your data attribute in middleware. If you want access then set your value in **`"Value"`** attribute of button.

Comment: @KiranJoshi in old Asp.Net webforms it was easy to get the submitting button by sender argument.

Comment: @KiranJoshi is there any way other than body to get html content? maybe via header or anything else

Comment: You can get from `Request.Form`

Comment: I'm afraid you can use a unvisiable input to store the value of `data-setting` then you can get form data in request content like other form elements.

Comment: thanks guys for your time. how can i use Request.Form to get form field and how to remove one of them after getting the field i need.